# How to ungroup the variable in SQL?

Tags: sql, amazon-athena

I have a query that I joined three different data sources: X, Y and Z. But I would like to have one more variable that shows me the minimum price from X data source. I mean that something like this:

```sql
MIN(price) as min_price
```

But this `min_price` should be only dependent on the `product_id`, so I should ignore the `shop_id` or other fields.

How can I do that or where can I put this?

```sql
SELECT co1.shop_id,
         co1.product_id,
         co1.price,
         co2.manufacturer_id,
         co2.category_id
FROM X AS co1
JOIN 
    (SELECT id,
         manufacturer_id,
         category_id
    FROM Y
    GROUP BY  id, manufacturer_id, category_id) AS co2
    ON co1.product_id = CAST(co2.id AS bigint)
JOIN Z
    ON co1.shop_id = Z.shop_id
WHERE site_id = 1
GROUP BY  co1.shop_id, co1.product_id, co2.manufacturer_id, co1.price, co2.category_id
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use window functions:

```
SELECT co1.shop_id, co1.product_id, co1.price,
       co2.manufacturer_id, co2.category_id,
       MIN(co1.price) OVER (PARTITION BY co1.product_id)
FROM . . .
```